# Esperar determinado tempo para executar - Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d

Estava tentando fazer quando toda vez que o NPC chegasse a determinado **Path** ele esperasse X tempo para ir para o próximo. Mas como estou chamando ele dentro do Update ele atualiza toda vez que `transform.position, paths[index].position) < 0.1f` Mas nesse caso quero que seja menor que 0.1f e que tenha passado mais de X segundos parado.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NPC_Path : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private float initialSpeed;

    private int index;
    private Animator anim;

    public List<Transform> paths = new List<Transform>();

    private void Start()
    {
        initialSpeed = speed;
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        //Verifica se existe o dialogo em andamento, se tiver ele para se não tiver ele anda
        if (DialogueControl.instance.isShowing)
        {
            speed = 0;
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }
        else
        {
            speed = initialSpeed;
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        }

        //Faz o NPC ir para a proxima possição
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, paths[index].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //Verifica se o NPC chegou na possição
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, paths[index].position) < 0.1f)
        {
            //Sorteia a posição
            index = Random.Range(0, paths.Count);
            
        }

        //Verifica a direção que o NPC tem que andar
        Vector2 direction = paths[index].position - transform.position;

        if (direction.x > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }
        if (direction.x < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 180);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá pra fazer uma contagem regressiva:

```
void Start()
{
  // Inicia a contagem
  StartCoroutine("contagemRegressiva");
}

IEnumerator contagemRegressiva()
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //Ou qualquer outro segundo
  //Faça:
  transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, paths[index].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Coloquei o StartCoroutine no start, mas você pode colocar para iniciar quando ele chegar na posição.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).